How to authenticate user with facebook in flask?
I'm developing a website. I use facebook to log in user. After validating user, it returns to homepage and shows user email with log in successfully message. If there is an error, it redirect to log in page. The issue is the user has to log in twice with facebook in order to show the email and welcome message. The first time returns to homepage with nothing displayed.
project
|___app
|   |
|   |___templates
|   |   |
|   |   |___log-in.html
|   |___init__.py
|   |
|   |___social_log_in.py
|   
|___config.py
|___main.py

social_log_in.py
from flask_dance.contrib.facebook import make_facebook_blueprint, facebook
from flask import redirect, url_for, flash
from . import db
from .model import User

facebook_bp = make_facebook_blueprint(
    client_id = Config.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret = Config.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    login_url='/facebook/login',
    scope=['email']
)

@facebook_bp.route('/post_login')
def facebook_login():
    if not facebook.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('facebook.login'))

    resp = facebook.get('/me?fields=id,name,email')
    if resp.ok:
        user_info = resp.json()
        email = user_info['email']      
        if not email:
            flash('Email not found in Facebook response.', 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.log_in'))
        # Check if user already exists
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if not user:
            # Create a new user if not exists
            user = User(email=email)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

        login_user(user)
        flash('Login successful!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.home'))
    else:
        flash('Failed to fetch user information from Facebook.', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.log_in'))

log-in.html
<a href="{{url_for('facebook.facebook_login')}}" class="form-control bg-info bg-gradient">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> Login with Facebook
</a>

config.py
class Config:    
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID'
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET'

init.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
from .social_log_in import facebook_bp
    app.register_blueprint(facebook_bp)
    return app

main.py
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

I'm hosting the web in pythonanywhere. I print out all mapped url using with app.test_request_context(): print('test all urls',app.url_map). The server logs <Rule '/facebook/login' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> facebook.login>,#012 <Rule '/facebook/authorized' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> facebook.authorized>,#012 <Rule '/authorized' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> facebook.facebook_login>. The flask_dance handles facebook login in facebook/login route and authorization automatically in /facebook/authorize route, but somehow it does not integrate well with the facebook authentication logic.
